# How could I use malloc for the two cv::Mat from my structure?

Tags: c++, malloc

I have defined a structure in a .h file, which keeps 2 cv::Mat. More exactly, this is the struct:

```
typedef struct Gradient {
    cv::Mat module;
    cv::Mat direction;
}Gradient;
```

Now in the .cpp file, i want to use it. So i use malloc to dynamically alloc space for the whole structure, like this:

```
Gradient *gradient = (Gradient*)malloc(sizeof(Gradient));
```

And now I know I would need to also allocate space for module and direction. How could I do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: this is c++, use new not malloc

Comment: `dynamically alloc space for the whole structure` `to also allocate space for module and direction` If you allocated space for "the whole structure" and structure consists of `module` and `direction`, then you already allocated space for them. "the whole structure" = `module` + `direction`

Comment: I think you should take @user advice into consideration. Using new vs malloc is not only about allocating the space for those member-variables, but calling their class constructor

Comment: You're using C++, why are you trying to allocate a structure like it's C? This wield just create problems down the road, since C++ object must be _constructed_ in addition to being _allocated_, and `malloc` only does half the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct Gradient {
    cv::Mat module;
    cv::Mat direction;
}Gradient;
```

call it as such :

```
Gradient *gradient = new(Gradient);
```

this is c++, use new, it allocates enough spaces and also construct the object.
This will use gradient's default constructor and therefore also use `cv::Mat` default constructor, twice (once for `module` and once for `direction`).
new returns a pointer to the newly constructed object.

Should you want to allocate without constructing, you can use the `allocator` template:

```
allocator<Gradient> alloc;
Gradient * ptr = alloc.allocate(1); // this will allocate enough space for one object
```

You will however need to construct the object, in which case you can also use placement new :

```
new (ptr) Gradient();
```

Comment: No need for `allocator`: just allocate a buffer of `char` of at least `sizeof(Gradient)`. You can then use placement new on that buffer.